# Reconhecimento de imagem/icone/figura na propria tela do computador em python

Tags: python, imagem, opencv

Estou iniciando estudo sobre reconhecimento de imagens, já cheguei a mexer com OpenCV fiz alguns testes básicos de reconhecimento de faces e alguns objetos que já vem na biblioteca, gostaria de capturar a tela ao invés de uma webcam para localizar algo na tela, como um icone ou algum outro elemento. Aproveitando o post, seria possivel ler um numero ou palavra em determinada área,

Comment: Conhece o sikuli? Ele faz isso que você quer, https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Eu também sou novato nesta área e não sei se tem um comando para Screenshots na biblioteca Opencv, mas existe a biblioteca pyscreenshot.

1º Deve instala-la:

```
pip install pyscreenshot - Windows
sudo pip instalar pyscreenshot - Linux
```

Para usar a captura de tela.

```
import pyscreenshot as pys

imagem = pys.grab() #Para tirar o Screenshots
imagem.show() # mostrar a imagem
imagem.save('test.jpg', 'jpeg') #Salva a imagem na pasta do arquivo e será.jpeg
```

E é só incrementar com a biblioteca cv2

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpeg',1)
cv2.imshow('captura de tela', img)
```

Eu não sei como ler um número ou palavra no cv2, mas creio que pode sim. Irei estudar sobre. Espero ter ajudado.

Mais sobre pyscreenshot
https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/